# Pandas DataFrame from list of dicts (couldnt find this config)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

from the following list of dicts

```
 d=[{u'identifier': u'AAPL', u'item': u'beta', u'value': 1.0448},
   {u'identifier': u'GOOG', u'item': u'three_yr_weekly_beta', u'value': 1.2656},
   {u'identifier': u'AAPL', u'item': u'legal_name', u'value': u'APPLE INC'},
   {u'identifier': u'GOOG', u'item': u'legal_name', u'value': u'Alphabet Inc.'},
   {u'identifier': u'AAPL',u'item': u'market_category',u'value': u'Common Stock'}]
```

I was able to get as far as

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d, index='item')
```

i would like for the columns to be the 'identifier' (AAPL and GOOG) rather than 'identifier' and 'value'

Comment: try,  `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d).set_index(['item', 'value'])`

Comment: Post your desired output please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need pivoting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).pivot('item','identifier','value')
#alternative solution
#df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index(['item','identifier'])['value'].unstack()
```

---

```
print (df)
identifier                    AAPL           GOOG
item                                             
beta                        1.0448            NaN
legal_name               APPLE INC  Alphabet Inc.
market_category       Common Stock            NaN
three_yr_weekly_beta           NaN         1.2656
```

Comment: this is the only thing that I could get to work :  df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index(['item','identifier'])['value'].unstack()